# Can't get Completion Block to execute using Firebase Simple Login with Email/Password

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-security, firebasesimplelogin

So I'm new to using Firebase, and iOS app development, and am trying to set up Simple Login following this [guide.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/simple-login/password.html)

For some reason though the completion block code never gets executed and a bool that i'm using to see if the user creation went okay is always NO. I tried to step through my code using the Debugger and when it got to the completion block it basically just jumped to the end of the method, very odd behavior. Here is my code:

```
BOOL goodFirebaseCall = false;

- (void)createUser:(NSString*)userName andPasswordis:(NSString*)password {

  goodFirebaseCall = [self createFirebaseUser:userName andPasswordis:password];

  if(goodFirebaseCall==true) //goodFirebaseCall is always NO
  {
      NSLog(@"Logged in, now adding the user to Firebase.");
      // Create a reference to a Firebase location
      Firebase* fUsers = [[Firebase alloc]    initWithUrl:@"https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/users"];

      Firebase* fNewUser = [fUsers childByAppendingPath:userName]; //childByAutoId];
      [fNewUser setValue:@{@"name":userName}];
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"Error, something went wrong with user creation");
   }
}

-(BOOL)createFirebaseUser:(NSString*)email andPasswordis:(NSString*)password
{
   goodFirebaseCall = false;
   Firebase* myRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/"];
   FirebaseSimpleLogin* authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:myRef];
   [authClient createUserWithEmail:@"email@domain.com" password:@"very secret"
             andCompletionBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser* user) {
                 if (error != nil) {
                     // There was an error creating the account
                     NSLog(@"%@", error);
                 } else {
                     // We created a new user account
                     goodFirebaseCall = true;
                     NSLog(@"User Created!");
                 }
             }];
    return goodFirebaseCall;
}
```

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated! I've been scratching my head as to why the completion block would never get called.

Thanks,
NuttGuy

Comment: Bear with me as I'm not an iOS guru, but don't you need to wait for the createUserWithEmail method to complete, since it's asynchronous, before goodFirebaseCall will be set? In other words, the completion block is not executed before `return goodFireabaseCall`, so it will never be set to true.

Comment: @Kato I had a similar thought after reading about how Firebase queues up actions like the createUserWithEmail method. But then, and this comes down to my lack of knowledge of Objective C, how do I make it wait until the createUserWithEmail method is complete that way goodFirebaseCall is actually set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `createUserWithEmail:password` synchronously, but completion blocks are actually executed asynchronously. This allows Firebase to operate in the background and not hang your UI. This means that code you want run *after* the createUser call should be *inside* the completion block. You could also use the completion block to call into another method that completes any extra user creation you want.

You can structure your code like this:

```
- (void)createUser:(NSString *)userName 
         withEmail:(NSString *)email 
       andPassword:(NSString *)password {

    [self createFirebaseUser:userName withEmail:email andPassword:password];
}


- (void)createFirebaseUser:userName 
                 withEmail:(NSString *)email 
               andPassword:(NSString *)password {

    Firebase* myRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/"];
    FirebaseSimpleLogin* authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:myRef];
    [authClient createUserWithEmail:email password:password
        andCompletionBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser* user) {
            if (error != nil) {
                // There was an error creating the account
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
                [self completeCreateUser:userName 
                        withFirebaseUser:user ifFirebaseSucceeds:NO];
            } else {
                 NSLog(@"User Created! %@", user);
                [self completeCreateUser:userName 
                        withFirebaseUser:user ifFirebaseSucceeds:YES];
            }
    }];
}

- (void)completeCreateUser:(NSString *)userName 
          withFirebaseUser:(FAUser *)user 
        ifFirebaseSucceeds:(BOOL)goodFirebaseCall {
    if (goodFirebaseCall) {
        NSLog(@"User created, but not logged in, now adding the user to Firebase.");
        // Create a reference to a Firebase location
        Firebase* fUsers = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/users"];

        Firebase* fNewUser = [fUsers childByAppendingPath:user.uid]; //childByAutoId];
       [fNewUser setValue:@{@"name":userName}];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error, something went wrong with user creation");
    }
}
```

So you see that it's the same if-statement surrounding `goodFirebaseCall`, but instead of waiting for the `BOOL` to be returned, you call another method from the completion block and pass it the `BOOL` you want "returned."

I tried to keep the code the same so that you could see where the segments moved, but you could put all of the code in the third method inside of the completion block if you wanted to. The one thing I did modify was to use `user.uid` as the path appended to the Firebase users reference since that will always be accessible in your security rules and on `FAUser` objects, which you'll get from logging in and such.

Also, `createUserWithEmail:password` will *not* log in your user. You will have to make another call to `loginWithEmail:andPassword:withCompletionBlock:` either inside the `createUserWithEmail:password` completion block, or in the third method.

Comment: Okay I tried the code as you described above, I didn't understand that Firebase Simple Login calls were async calls so it makes sense to me why the completion block wasn't getting executed. This might be an issue with my lack of Obj C knowledge, but I ran into an issue with the code above as well, basically it gets to the completion block in the 'createFirebaseUser' method, jumps to the end of the method and goes back to the iOS Simulator but the UI is completely non responsive. I can still pull down the Notification Center but I can't interact with the UI in the app at all.

Comment: I guess another question I have is when does the completion block get called? Just at some point after you call `createUserWithEmail:password`?

Comment: Oops, I found my problem. Stupid Copy Pasta and I left in the xxxx in my firebase URL, thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: The completion block is called after Firebase hits the server. This gives Firebase the chance to either a) create the user or b) let you know what the error is. As far as your app is concerned, yeah, that is just at some point after you call `createuserWithEmail:password`. And yup. Got to change those xxxxs. :)